# how to set width,height etc to particular table in html

Tags: html, css, html-table

i have a table whose height and width and border has to be set. I have tried this css

```
table,td,tr#cer_actuals {
    padding-left: 5px;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 9pt;
    font-weight: normal;
    height: 0px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

this affects all the table in the project , so i have tried this ,

```
#cer_actuals {
    padding-left: 5px;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 9pt;
    font-weight: normal;
    height: 0px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

and HTML

```
<table  width="100%" id="cer_actuals" > 
<tr>
                                                <td align="left" width="10%"  style="background-color:#f1e0ff;"></td>
                                                <td align="center" width="20%" style="background-color:#f1e0ff;">
                                                    Mth
                                                </td>
                                                <td align="center" width="30%" style="background-color:#f1e0ff;">
                                                    Actuals
                                                </td>
                                                <td align="center" width="40%" style="background-color:#f1e0ff;">
                                                    EOY Accruals
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="left" width="10%"  style="background-color:#f1e0ff;"></td>
                                                <td align="center" width="20%" style="background-color:#f1e0ff;">C/F</td>
                                                <td  align="center" width="30%" style="background-color:white;">
                                                            <input type="text" id="CIMtrek_CI_Act_CF" name="CIMtrek_CI_Act_CF">
                                                                <xsl:attribute name="value"><xsl:value-of
                                                                    select="//Record/CIMtrek_CI_Act_CF/text()" /></xsl:attribute>
                                                            </input>
                                                </td>
                                                <td  align="center" width="40%" style="border-width:1px 0px 0px 1px;">

                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
```

but this has no effect on the table.

I have to set height for the td in the table.

How to do this.

Please help.

Comment: I think you should specify "some content", because in this way, the "some content" is not in table context. Needs tr and td tags, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this

```
#cer_actuals td {
    padding-left: 5px;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 9pt;
    font-weight: normal;
    height: 0px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/WsLcT/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

add this:

```
#cer_actuals td {
  height: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this -

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>Some Content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Some Content</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
table td{
  padding: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

please try:

## cer_actuals tr td {...}

"#cer_actuals - means all elements with id = cer_actuals;
tr - means all table row from what we get before
td - means all td from what we get before"